# How to list down all defined macros in Teradata?

Tags: sql, macros, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have created few macros in Teradata. But now im not remembering all the macro names . Can anyone please help me to retrieve all defined macros in Teradata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dbc.tablesV` view to get all macros:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbc.tablesV
WHERE tablekind = 'M' -- table (T), view (V), macro (M), stored procedure (P)
;
```

Depending on your `TD` version, you may have a couple different versions of the view available: `dbc.tables`, `dbc.tablesV`, `dbc.tablesX`, `dbc.tablesVX`:

```
V - supports extended object names (128 characters)
X - only shows objects the current user has permission to
VX - combination of the two
```

[TD Manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/9oYJKOEctNZOOpLH68GHVA/EeUqx_Cbk5ELgPzXbIn~2w)
[Reference](http://www.dbmstutorials.com/teradata/teradata_data_dictionary_queries.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. This resolves my issue. Thank you again